# Create files with PC8 character set

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, download, iso-8859-1

I'm going crazy, I have searched this and other forums since I got a file specification that tells the files my code produces should use PC8-characters (also known as CP437 or ISO-8859-1), it's a rather plain text file and contains international characters like Å (decimal 143), Ä (decimal 142) and Ö (decimal 148).

My code produces a string containing all characters that should be in the file and I can get a Unicode-version of it (I also succeeded to create a UTF8 version of the but it's useless in this case).

It would also be great if the file could be downloaded but I don't get any success with that either, the browser does not receive any file, I checked the antivirus and tried another browser without success.

For the moment I written a possibility to mail the file and that works fine.

In the case when I send the file by mail the code (without any encoding) looks like this:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(ReceiverMail, ReceiverName));
msg.From = new MailAddress(SenderMail, SenderName);
msg.Subject = Subject;
msg.Body = Body;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
sw.Write(StringToSend);
sw.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
Attachment at = new Attachment(ms, FileName);
msg.Attachments.Add(at);
using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
    smtp.Send(msg);
}
```

In the case when I wan't to download the file in the browser my code looks like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
sw.Write(StringToSend);
sw.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;
Response.Write(ms);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

ISO-8859-1 is also known as Latin-1, you can get an encoder for this character set like this:

```
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
```

In your Response example you can use then this with `Response.ContentEncoding`:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);

Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Response.Write(stringToSend);

Response.Flush();
```

Comment: I tried the code you submitted but unfortunately I don't get any download at all so I don't even can check if the character set is correct.